# Gatling repeat with connection re-use

Tags: gatling

With Gatling 2, is it possible to repeat with connection re-use? How?

I have the below code, but it appears to open new connection every time. I want to maintain x connections for some time.

```
val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("http://mysrv.pvt")
        .inferHtmlResources()

val uri1 = "http://mysrv.pvt"

val scn = scenario("Simulation").repeat(50){
        pause(2 seconds,20 seconds).
        exec(http("request_0")
                .get("/s1/serve.html")
        )
        }

setUp(scn.inject(
            atOnceUsers(20000)
  ).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your question is not accurate enough.

By default, Gatling has one connection pool per virtual user, so each of them do re-use connections between sequential requests, and can have more than one concurrent connection when dealing with resource fetching, which you do as you enabled `inferHtmlResources`. This way, virtual users behave as independent browsers.

You can change this behavior and share a common connection pool, see [doc](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_protocol.html#connection-sharing). However, you have to make sure this makes sense in your case. Your workload profile will be very different, the toll on the TCP stack on both the client/Gatling and the server/your app will be way less, so make sure that's how your application is being used in production.

Comment: Hmm .. ok .. As I said end goal is to maintain 20k connections for few minutes with occasional requests .. I did try shareConnections; but then instead of 20K connections there were only 300 or so .. which is probably as designed since the doc says users will share the connections.

Comment: You pause between 2 and 20 seconds, so there's a very good chance your server will close idle connections between consecutive requests.